# Uncaught exception [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key btnAvatar

Tags: objective-c, storyboard-reference

```
2017-04-13 12:16:36.606 Boardmeeting[4601:1375127] Uncaught exception [<UIViewController 0x7f988fe32750> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key btnAvatar.
2017-04-13 12:16:36.611 Boardmeeting[4601:1375127] Stack trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f555d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010efbe21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f555c99 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010d25e9df -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010d90d293 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010db8179e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4fa9e0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010db80122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d9139c5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d9142e7 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d91461c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d914e70 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d9734f3 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 483
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d972935 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 59
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d96e7f6 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 365
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010d96e57b -[UITabBarController setSelectedIndex:] + 131
    16  Boardmeeting                        0x0000000109746bce -[LoginViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 350
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010df4817f -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 353
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010df47fed -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010d917a1f -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 99
    20  Boardmeeting                        0x00000001097470ee -[LoginViewController requestFinished:] + 446
    21  Boardmeeting                        0x00000001096fbe9e -[ASIHTTPRequest reportFinished] + 142
    22  Foundation                          0x000000010d27ee9e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 326
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4fa761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4df98c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4dee76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f4de884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000115158a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010d772c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    29  Boardmeeting                        0x0000000109758eae main + 142
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011067b68d start + 1
)
```

Comment: provide some code or check when this problem comes by adding brekpoints

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you remove an IBOutlet from a class, but you don't remove the outlet link in the storyboard.

In your case it's btnAvatar: could you have removed this from your class/controller but you left it there on the storyboard?

Comment: Nope, it is already there and it shows correct link in the connection inspector!

Comment: As you can see from the stacktrace it's a "runtime outlet connection" so it's definitely an outlet problem, and btnAvatar is mentioned so... check better. Remove and do it again, if needed

Comment: @RezoanulAlamRiad And "UIViewController" is really the class name you use? Didn't you forgot to set the real class for your UIViewController? (You may have set it, linked the IBOutlet, but afterwards remove the class).

Comment: @Larme, Yes I've set the actual class name of UIViewController, I've checked many times!

Comment: It should be UIViewController, it should be the name of the class in which you created bntAvatar